# Excel Calculating Relative Position

Tags: excel

I'm new here, and I thought I would ask a question that certainly isn't found in the Microsoft Help Center and that I haven't been able to find a solution to either.

I am trying to calculate probability on things, and for the most part, Excel is very helpful in it. I'm running into problems though as I add additional variables.

My sheet currently is comparing dice rolls of 4 8-sided dice. 2 dice have certain symbols and the two other dice have different symbols. Some symbols negate each other, and in the end I come to a damage output number. When comparing 2 or 3 dice, the possible combinations are limited. 3 dice having 512 possibilities. With 4 now, there are 4096 possibilities and it's only going to get higher. This is why I need what I'm asking for.

Is there a way for a cell to understand is current position in reference to the block of cells it's currently in?

For example: I'm calculating a reroll possibility, but it will only happen half the time, meaning there are 12 possibilities of a single die with reroll option. So the current possibility table I'm developing is going to be 96 separate tables of 96 possible outcomes each. Table 1/1 is going to compare the first row of the 2 dice Attack roll table vs. the first row of the 2 dice Defense roll table. Row 1 Column 1 of this table is going to give the outcome of R1C1 of Attack table vs. R1C1 of Defense table. R1C2 of the table is going to give the outcome of R1C1 of Attack table vs. R1C2 of Defense table. R2C1 of this table will give the outcome of R1C2 of Attack table vs. R1C1 of Defense table, etc...

I know how to do the referencing to the tables, so I've made it so once I build one table, I can copy and paste it to build the other 96. But as I compare more dice rolls, this will quickly become too cumbersome to handle. If there is a way for a cell to understand where it's relative position is in a given block of cells (i.e. R2C1 of my example table understands that it is R2C1), it would cut down on my load immensely, and allow for me to continue building these probability tables so o can better understand tradeoffs in certain areas.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done something this before to check some odds on things. Whether or not you get a solution working, I highly recommend you just stop trying to do it with Excel and use a programming language - such as VBA. Doing mult-dimensional IF-THEN blocks on a 2D grid is very painful.

Comment: I agree with @Grade'Eh'Bacon that VBA is definitely the way to go. I've done some simulations of RISK battles in VBA with very little trouble. It is easy to write the VBA so as to send the output to rows in Excel.

Comment: would this help you? `=CELL("address")`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm well versed in VBA for Access, is it much different in Excel? I guess I also would need to know where to start. I'm trying to calculate things like rerolls, and with optional rerolls, I calculated there would be 46,656 dice combinations just with 3 attack dice. How can VBA be leveraged to reduce the leg work?

Comment: @Raven19528 VBA is VBA. The application object model is of course different, but writing a pure VBA sub or function is the same in both cases. If you described the rules behind the dice and what you are trying to accomplish then you could probably get a more focused answer. Obviously you can set up a loop which goes through all possible rolls of the dice, but how you would use such a loop seems unclear.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you. I've gotten some basis down for it, but was wondering if there are any tricks I'm missing. For instance, if I know I have 3 dice rolling, I know I need a three dimensional array to hold the results. I can use a select case construct to do this, but was wondering if there was a better/easier way. Second, you mentioned a loop to go through all the rolls. Is there any other way to get the results from an array. I.e. is there a way to count the 12 combinations of '7' out of the 36 possible in a 2 six-sided dice roll without iterating through the entire array of results?

Comment: @Raven19528 How do you get 12 combinations of 7? x+y = 7 has 6 rather than 12 solutions for x,y in 1-6. A useful trick when tabulating dice rolls is to think of k rolls of an n-sided die as being an integer in the range 0 to n^k-1 -- written in base n. This allows you to use a single for loop to iterate through all possibilities, albeit at the cost of encoding/decoding dice roll vectors as integers. If you ask a more focused question I could post any relevant VBA code.

Comment: @JohnColeman I feel dumb. I counted the possibilities twice. Been staring at this too long. So I could be rolling anywhere from 1-8 8 sided dice. That's where I need to start. I have the dice being used as 8 element arrays already, and they are integer values so they can be added together.  I've done the encoding already, and once I know how to gather the results, the decoding won't be too difficult. I've broken it up into Attack and Defense rolls in the code, so eventually I'll also need to add the attack results array to the defense results array.

Comment: What's the best way to iterate through the array and count the number of results? Especially since the array could be anywhere from 1 to 8 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Excel UDF I wrote for basic dice calculation %. It may not work directly for your example with negative/conditional outcomes, but it does have flexibility for testing more than one dice and the number of sides dice, so it might inspire you with some ideas. As previous comments suggested, if you gave exact parameters, you could probably get a specific example. My example returns a %. It currently only measures the probability of a single outcome, but you could do more than one formula per cell `=DiceRollOdds(3,2)+DiceRollOdds(4,2)` (to measure the probability of 3 and 4), or you can modify the code get something more specific.

```
Function DiceRollOdds(OutcomeToCheck As Integer, NumberOfDice As Integer, Optional SidesOnDice As Integer) As Double
Dim SuccessResult As Integer, FailedResult As Integer, SingleDice As Integer, RollResult As Integer

If SidesOnDice = 0 Then
    SidesOnDice = 6
End If

Dim Rolls As Integer

For Rolls = 1 To (SidesOnDice ^ NumberOfDice)
RollResult = 0
    For SingleDice = 0 To NumberOfDice - 1

        RollResult = Int(Rolls / SidesOnDice ^ SingleDice) Mod SidesOnDice + 1 + RollResult
    Next SingleDice

If RollResult = OutcomeToCheck Then
    SuccessResult = SuccessResult + 1
Else
    FailedResult = FailedResult + 1
End If

Next Rolls

DiceRollOdds = SuccessResult / (FailedResult + SuccessResult)

End Function
```